# Tree query algorithm fails test cases

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, segment-tree

A tree is a simple graph in which every two vertices are connected by exactly one path. You are given a rooted tree with  vertices and a lamp is placed on each vertex of the tree.

You are given  queries of the following two types:

```
1 v: You switch the lamp placed on the vertex v, that is, either from On to Off or Off to On.
2 v: Determine the number of vertices connected to the subtree of v if you only consider the lamps that are in On state. In other words, determine the number of vertices in the subtree of v , such as u, that can reach from v by using only the vertices that have lamps in the On state.
```

Note: Initially, all the lamps are turned On and the tree is rooted from vertex number .

Input format

First line: Two integers  and  denoting the number of vertices and queries
Next  lines: Two number  and  denoting an edge between the vertices  and
Next  lines: Two integers  and , where  is the type of the  query
Note: It is guaranteed that these edges form a tree rooted from vertex .

Output format
For every query of type 2, print the answer in a single line.

Constraints

```
SAMPLE INPUT 
5 4
1 2
2 3
1 4
4 5
1 3
2 2
1 3
2 2
SAMPLE OUTPUT 
1
2
```

Explanation:

This is the tree in the first place:

[image]

The tree after turning off lamp in node
Obviously the answer now for vertex  is

[image]

Code:

```
void updateSubSwitches(vector<vector<int>> &tree,vector<int> &parent, vector<int> &switchesSubTree, int vertex, bool flag) {
    if(flag) {
        switchesSubTree[vertex]=1;
        for(int i=0;i<tree[vertex].size();i++) {
            switchesSubTree[vertex] += switchesSubTree[tree[vertex][i]];
        }
        int parentVertex=parent[vertex];
        while(switchesSubTree[parentVertex]!=0 && parentVertex!=0) {
            switchesSubTree[parentVertex]=switchesSubTree[parentVertex]+switchesSubTree[vertex];
            parentVertex=parent[parentVertex];
        }
        if(parentVertex == 0) {
        switchesSubTree[0]=switchesSubTree[0]+switchesSubTree[vertex];
        }
    } else {
        int parentVertex=parent[vertex];
        while(switchesSubTree[parentVertex]!=0 && parentVertex!=0) {
            switchesSubTree[parentVertex]=switchesSubTree[parentVertex]-switchesSubTree[vertex];
            parentVertex=parent[parentVertex];
        }
        if(parentVertex == 0) {
        switchesSubTree[0]=switchesSubTree[0]-switchesSubTree[vertex];
        }
        switchesSubTree[vertex]=0;
    }
}
 
int initialSubSwitches(vector<vector<int>> &tree, vector<int> &switchesSubTree,int vertex) {
    if(switchesSubTree[vertex] == -1) { 
        if(tree[vertex].size() > 0) {
            switchesSubTree[vertex] = 1;
            //cout<<vertex<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<tree[vertex].size();i++){
            
            switchesSubTree[vertex] += initialSubSwitches(tree,switchesSubTree,tree[vertex][i]);
            
            
        } 
        return switchesSubTree[vertex];
    } else {
        //cout<<vertex<<endl;
            switchesSubTree[vertex] = 1;
            return 1;
    }
        }
}
 
int main() {
    int n,q;
    cin>>n>>q;
    vector<vector<int>> tree(n);
    vector<bool> arr(n,true);
    vector<int> switchesSubTree(n,-1);
    vector<int> parent(n);
    for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++) {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        tree[a-1].push_back(b-1);
        parent[b-1] = a-1;
    }
    
    initialSubSwitches(tree,switchesSubTree,0);

 
    for(int i=1;i<=q;i++) {
        int b,v;
        cin>>b>>v;
        if(b==1) {
            arr[v-1]=!arr[v-1];
            updateSubSwitches(tree,parent,switchesSubTree,v-1,arr[v-1]);
        } else {
            cout<<switchesSubTree[v-1]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Algorithm:

Initialization

1. tree stores the graph
2. arr stores if lamp at vertex v is ON or OFF.
3. switchesSubTree stores the number of lamps swtiched ON for that subtree.

Steps:

```
 1. initialize the switchesSubTree array if initially all lamps are ON.
    2. For each query, 
     2.1 if lamp is turned OFF:
           decrease its ancestors by switchesSubTree[vertex] until we get a node whose lamp is OFF or we reach root vertex
           make switchesSubTree[vertex] = 0
     2.2 if lamp is turned ON:
           calculate no. of lamps swithced ON for this vertex which is 
             switchesSubTree[vertex] = 1 + sum(all lamps of children)
           increase the lamps for ancestors until we get a node whose lamp is OFF or we reach root vertex.
```

But solution gives TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED for some test cases and also wrong for some test cases.
Where am I going wrong and what can be an efficient and better solution ?

Comment: I couldn't understand what the problem asks exactly and I couldn't understand what the queries do.

Comment: It sounds like query type `1` toggles the lamp state, and query type `2` returns the number of "on" lamps beneath and including the specified node? And TLE stands for "time limit exceeded"? The best way to debug this is to look specifically at the test cases that are failing and walk through your code (with pencil and paper) to understand where it's not returning what you expect. For the cases that exceed their time limits, consider ways to make your algorithm more efficient.

Comment: It looks like this is copied and pasted from https://www.hackerearth.com/de/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/segment-trees/practice-problems/algorithm/tree-query-3-5d98588f/, though with some transcription errors (missing notation in a few places).

Comment: Skimming the code you have, it looks logical to me. It seems efficient (modifications to the tree happen in O(lg(n)) time in the average case), and seems correct. I would need to see a specific example that's failing to understand the problem. It's probably an edge case of some kind.